# Error: Incomplete code - cannot handle first arg of type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval)

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have an excel with a lot of formulae in it and I need to replicate it in my java code so I have used Apache POI.

Using Apache POI we generate a workBook object. We update the input fields in the workBook object and read the output fields from the workBook object and store them in our java class object.

When I am trying to evaluate a formulae cell using Apache POI I am getting an error as:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Incomplete code - cannot handle first arg of type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Index.convertFirstArg(Index.java:106)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Index.evaluate(Index.java:50)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Index.evaluate(Index.java:114)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:36)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.UnaryPlusEval.evaluate(UnaryPlusEval.java:38)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed1ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed1ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
```

All the functionalities are working fine in the excel.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What's the formula you're trying to evaluate? And did you try with the most recent version of Apache POI?

Comment: I am using the latest stable version of Apache POI( Apache POI 3.15).
Since there are so many formulae and excel sheet is too huge, I don't know how to debug which one is creating difficulty.

Comment: Add some logging to your code, and see the last cell/formula before the exception?

Comment: We had the same issue and created https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61116 (including workbook for reproducing)